Problems with ArcTan making a jump
I have a function let's call $f(j,h)$ that gives me two points in $\mathbb{R}$ depending on $(j,h)$ and then of these two points in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ I want to find the angle given by the two points using the function $ArcTan[x,y]$ of Mathematica. Now my problem is that I want to do this in a continuous manner and it seems that Mathematica in a example does a jump of $2\pi$ i.e. gives the negative angle and then jumps to positive values. Is there a way that I can avoid this jump , since I wanted something continuous ?


Angle between two points? That makes no sense. What is the code of your plot or do we have to guess it?

I guess I didn't phrase it write , say you have $(x,y)$ then its $\theta$ such that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. The reason I didn't provide the code is because there are a lot of functions for defining $f(j,h)$ and I just wanted to understand how to tackle this $ArcTan$ problem.

So it is angle between vector {x,y} and x axis. There are also functions VectorAngle and PlanarAngle that may suit you better than ArcTan. Without code you hardly get a better answer.

Thank you I'll look into it. Is it possible to tell Mathematica only to return non-positive values of ArcTan ?

ArcTan is a multivalued function. Therefore one has to choose a branch. The main branch is defined so that ArcTan is a value between -Pi/2 and Pi/2.

Without knowing the details, perhaps you want to move the branch?  Mod[ArcTan[x,y],2 Pi] ?

"Unwrapping" is the term for making the line continuous by implicitly choosing the appropriate branch for each point. (Only possible if you are processing a range of values, e.g. when plotting the function, or tabulating it.)
ResourceFunction["PhaseUnwrap"]

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PhaseUnwrap
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1340126
